# What would the notation for this binary string look like?

Tags: combinatorics, notation, regular-expressions, bit-strings

Every block of 1's of length $\ge 4$ cannot be followed by a block of 0's of length $\ge 4$, and any block of 1s of length 1, 2 or 3 must be followed by a block of 0s whose length is congruent to 1 mod 4.

The answer I came up with is this:
$$\{0\}^*\{(1111)(1)^*\{0, 00, 000\}, \{1, 11, 111\}0(0000)^*\}^*$$

The problem is, it cannot produce some strings like $11111$. What would the proper notation look like.

Comment: "Followed by" means "immediately followed by" right?  We're just looking at the very next block, not all subsequent bocks?  Also, why isn't $11111$ legal?

Comment: $11111$ is legal, but my notation cannot produce it.

Comment: Yes, I misread what you said sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that you’re just missing the possibility of terminating with a string of ones. You can fix that by adding one more piece:

$$\{0\}^*\{(1111)(1)^*\{0,00,000\},\{1,11,111\}0(0000)^*\}^*\{(1111)(1)^*,\lambda\}$$

Here $\lambda$ is the empty word.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think about it that way, I kept putting the last part after $\{0\}^*$ and it made it ambiguous.

Comment: @MasterBoggins: You’re welcome!